# Adjust user specified date & time (converted using mktime) to specific timezone

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

I've been scratching my head about this for a few hours now and decided to ask for some help.

I am using a javascript calendar to allow users to select a date and time. Now I want this time to be relative to THEIR timezone (which I already have recorded in a database). However I can't wrap my head around how to store the input. I know I need to adjust the UTC timestamp that mktime will spit out to the user's timezone but I'm having trouble with it.

This is what I've tried:

```
$time = $_POST['datetime']; // Dont worry I will sanitize the input
echo $time.'<br>';
$timezone = "Canada/Pacific"; // Just an example, this will be taken from the database
$timestamp = mktime($hours, $minute, 0, $month, $day, $year); // Based on $time, I just ignored my steps to get the hours etc here
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo 'Your timezone: '.date("F j Y h:i:s A", $timestamp).'<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo 'UTC: '.date("F j Y h:i:s A", $timestamp);
```

When I do the above the output I get is:

```
30 October 2013 - 01:00 AM
Your timezone: October 29 2013 11:00:00 PM
UTC: October, 30 2013 06:00:00 AM
```

The issue is that although the user enters 1:00 AM, I was expecting mktime to be converting it to a UTC timestamp of 1:00, however it seems like its being converted to a UTC timestamp where its actually 6:00 AM. I can't figure out where the 5 hour difference is coming from, and I don't want to code a static 5 hour difference in there.

After thats fixed though, I'd like to save the timestamp as a UTC timestamp that has been adjusted such that if I were to take the timestamp in the future and do:

```
$timezone = "Canada/Pacific";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
echo 'Time: '.date("F j Y h:i:s A", $timestamp); // $timestamp from the database
```

That it should output:

```
30 October 2013 - 01:00 AM
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php), and your life will be easier.

If posted datetime is in UTC, you can simple create DateTime object in UTC timezone like this:

```php
$dt = new DateTime($_POST['datetime'], new DateTimezone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('F j Y h:i:s A P');
```

If you wish to change timezone to users, you can call `setTimezone()` on DateTime object:

```php
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Canada/Pacific'));
echo $dt->format('F j Y h:i:s A P');
```

Try **[demo](https://eval.in/67053)**.

---

If your posted datetime is like `30 October 2013 - 01:00 AM`, then you cannot use `new DateTime()` or `strtotime()` because it is not standard datetime format. In that case, you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) like this:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y - h:i A', $_POST['datetime'], new DateTimezone('UTC'));
```

Try **[demo](https://eval.in/67055)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes my life much easier!

Comment: @user2988034: no problem, glad I can help. Told you so ;)

Comment: wow! didn't use DateTime() earlier that much. You helped me to solve me a month-long issue! :)